# iOS Find if another app was launched

Tags: ios, launch

How can I check if another app has been launched? I do not have to launch the other app, I just need to be notified whenever the other app has been launched using my app.

Comment: _“…has been launched using my app.”_ What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: Most likely via the Internet, if all parties cooperate.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible unless you are the developer of both apps.  There are good reasons Apple doesn't allow this, I'm sure you can think of some.  There's even a term for this that brings back childhood memories... if you ever played in a sandbox...

Comment: Thank you HackyStack. Is there any way I could find out anything about any other app being launched? This means I am not concerned about which app, but only concerned about any other app being launched. Or is it not possible at all(unless i developed both the apps)

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not possible at all.